# How to wait for CSV to be passed back and resolve promise in ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs, csv, promise

Currently the `fetchData()` passes back the csv in chunks (there's 3500 items in total), so I used `.then` to wait till it's completed to pass it to the papaparse function. However, in my console I see it moves onto `getArtist` before the promise is resolved. Thus, the array passed back to object is only some of the csv file and not the whole thing.

```
import React from 'react';
import Papa from 'papaparse';

export default function GetData(artist) {
    const object = fetchCsv().then(object => Papa.parse(object));
    console.log(object);
    const tateArtist = getArtist(artist, object);
    console.log(tateArtist);
    return tateArtist;
}

async function fetchCsv() {
    const response = await fetch('data/artist_data.csv');
    const reader = response.body.getReader();
    const result = await reader.read();
    const decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');
    const csv = await decoder.decode(result.value);
    return csv;
}

async function getArtist(artist, data){
   const artistName = artist.split(" ");
   var artistData = "Error";
   for(const item of data.data){
      if(item[1].includes(artistName[0]) && item[1].includes(artistName[artistName.length-1])){
         return item;
      }
   }
    return artistData;
}
```

I tried to wrap the line using `useEffect` , but instead got an error about incorrect usage.

```
export default function GetData(artist) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchCsv().then(object => Papa.parse(object)).then(response => setData(response));
  }, [])
```

Comment: I think you're looking for the [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) keyword

Comment: I'm not sure if you can combo `async` with `.then`. I only know `async`, `await` is a combo. Your code does make sense, since I assume `async` is a promise, but does it support `then` ?

Comment: @windmaomao I've done a similar thing in another file which seemed to have work as long as they are not within the same function. `.then` is executing sooner than it should though :/

Comment: Or the below `tateArtist` is executing sooner than it should before the above is done.

Comment: You're right, @Winsome. You can mix `then` with `async`. Ok i think the location of this `console.log` might have some issue, you can try to put console.log inside the `then`. Basically `then`  does not have a blocking feature as in `await`.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I converted the CSV file to a JSON, so it would make my life easier when reading items from the object. Plus less lines of code.

```
import React from 'react';
import artistData from './data/artist_data.json';

export default function getData(artist) {
    const tateArtist = getArtist(artist, artistData);
    return tateArtist;
}

async function getArtist(artist, artistData){
   const artistName = artist.split(" ");
   var tateArtist = "Error";
   artistData.some(function(data){
      var name = data.name;
      if(name.includes(artistName[0]) && name.includes(artistName[artistName.length-1])){
         tateArtist =  data;
         return;
      }
   })
    return tateArtist;
}
```